# convert string to float in my database column have float type

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web application, i need to display grid view in one column message string type that column have float data type in database. I am trying to convert string to float data type but it is not display properly what i have to do.

I tried this:

```
 string str1 = "Hi hello";
 float f = float.Parse(str1);
```

I am getting an exception like:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Is It Possible to convert string to float. Can anyone tell me how to do this.

Comment: To which float value should `"Hi hello"` evaluate? 42? 0? -1?

Comment: What you have is correct, but your input isn't a number - hence the error. If you want to be able to cope with erroneous input you need to either catch the exception and deal with it or use `TryParse`.

Comment: If the string contains number, then you can convert it to float. For string, you can't for sure.

Comment: Please show us an example of something typical that you expect to provide to `float.Parse` **and**  what you expect to get as a result. The example you've provided makes it hard for us to tell if `float.Parse` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*float.Parse* throws an exception in case str1 is not a number. If you wish to check whether you value is a parsable float at all use *float.TryParse*:

```
string str1 = "7";
float x;
 if(float.TryParse(str1,out x))
 {
      Console.Write(x); //returns 7
 }
 else
 {    
    Console.Write("Your error message");
 }
```